# Ver código fuente de un método nativo de Javascript.[native code]

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo. Si pongo `Array.prototype.slice` en la consola de Chrome, me devuelve

```
    function slice() { [native code] }
```

¿Se puede acceder de algún modo a "[native code]" ?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no lo puedes ver en la consola directamente, ya como dice el nombre `native code` => es nativo y la  mayoría de los códigos están escrito en C o C++.

Te dejo unos links donde podrás ver el código fuente de la misma:

Google - [V8](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/adminViews) y [Chromium](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc)

Firefox - [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey) y [Mercurial](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/)

Safari - [SquirrelFish](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/SquirrelFish)